# Motor shield and sensors

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega

While making a Arduino programmed maze runner Will bipolar motor shield be more beneficial than using tb6612fng motor shield???? Also which type of sensors will be better??

Comment: No. Especially with battery power you want to use a low-loss FET bridge rather than a bipolar one.  Sensors choices depend a lot on the maze pathway size, rules such as if you can see over the walls, etc.